# Lag when devices are connected via wi-fi

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I'm not sure it's the right site for this question, but here is the problem.

I've a console linked with a cable to a router. My internet connection is far from the best but when there aren't other devices it's mostly smooth.

The problem is that whenever I connect a tablet or a smartphone with wi fi to the same router i begin to experience lag in game.

I feel it's strange because it happens even if I'm just browsing the internet. So I'm asking if a similar behaviour is normal and, if not, how can I solve the problem.

I've a Alice Gate VoIP 2 Plus Wi-Fi router connected (with cables) to a decoder, an xbox 360 and an xbox one. I've this problem while I play with the xbox one and the other devices are turned off (I don't know for certain if the xbox 360 has the same problems). Then I've via wi-fi two ipads and my iphone 4S but using only one of these it's enough to cause the problem.

I asked the same question in 
Network Engineering(https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/23042/lag-when-devices-are-connected-via-wi-fi ) and they redirected me here.